# Re-Formating a CSV file

Tags: powershell

First time here and noob on powershell so please be gentle.

I have a CSV file looking like this.

Destination Well Position (Label),Reagents (no vol),Full (Constituent + Tube) ID
A1,RdRP,Sample1 
B1,RdRP,Sample2 
C1,RdRP,Sample3 
D1,RdRP,Sample4 
E1,RdRP,Sample5

I need to work it so that it looks like this

Row,Column,*Target Name,*Sample Name 
A,1,RDRP,Sample1 
B,1,RDRP,Sample2 
C,1,RDRP,Sample3 
D,1,RDRP,Sample4 
E,1,RDRP,Sample5

And then an Output name: blabla.csv.

i started doing this:

```bsh
$CVSOutput = '\test.csv'
$CVSInput = '\Export.csv'
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($CVSOutput)

$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = 'Row,Column,*Target Name,*Sample Name'

$Workbook2 = $excel.Workbooks.open($CVSInput)

$Worksheet = $Workbook2.WorkSheets.item(“Export”)
$Worksheet.activate()
$range = $WorkSheet.Range(“A2:A10”).CurrentRegion
$range.Copy() | out-null
$Worksheet2 = $Workbook.Worksheets.item(“test”)
$worksheet2.activate()
$range2 = $Worksheet2.Range(“A2:A10”)
$Worksheet2.Paste($range2)
$workbook.Save()
$workbook.close($false)
$Excel.Quit()
```

I Quicly realised im on the wrong path and have tryed lots more.. Anyone else have any ide for a script on this.

Answer (score 2):

[iRon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64553004/9898643) is nice and concise, but in this case, you have a file with (rather ugly) headers.
To make the code to convert this a bit more readable for you, I'd suggest using a ForEach-Object loop to convert the input data.

Something like

```
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheInputFile.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # -match creates $matches objects, in this case no. 1 --> Row letter(s) and no. 2 --> Column index
    $null = $_.'Destination Well Position (Label)' -match '([a-z]+)(\d+)'
    # output an object with the new columns and rename the others
    $_ | Select-Object @{Name = 'Row'; Expression = {$matches[1]}},
                       @{Name = 'Column'; Expression = {$matches[2]}},
                       @{Name = 'Target Name'; Expression = {$_.'Reagents (no vol)'}},
                       @{Name = 'Sample Name'; Expression = {$_.'Full (Constituent + Tube) ID'}}
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to new csv
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheResult.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
Row Column Target Name Sample Name
--- ------ ----------- -----------
A   1      RdRP        Sample1    
B   1      RdRP        Sample2    
C   1      RdRP        Sample3    
D   1      RdRP        Sample4    
E   1      RdRP        Sample5
```

Of course, you need to change the paths for both the input csv file ('D:\Test\TheInputFile.csv') and the output file ('D:\Test\TheResult.csv') to match your environment.

<sup>I have added switch `-UseCulture`, so the delimiter used in the output csv will be the same as your local Excel would expect it. If in your system the separator is a comma, you can leave that out</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the Excel cmdlet for this:

```
$Test = ConvertFrom-CSV -Header RC,Target,Sample @'
A1,RdRP,Sample1
B1,RdRP,Sample2
C1,RdRP,Sample3
D1,RdRP,Sample4
E1,RdRP,Sample5
'@

$Test | Select-Object @{ n="Row"; e={ $_.RC -replace '\d' } }, 
                      @{ n="Column"; e={ $_.RC -replace '\D' } }, 
                      Target, Sample
```

```
Row Column Target Sample
--- ------ ------ ------
A   1      RdRP   Sample1
B   1      RdRP   Sample2
C   1      RdRP   Sample3
D   1      RdRP   Sample4
E   1      RdRP   Sample5
```

Explanation:

- These `@{ n="Row"; e={ $_.RC -replace '\d' } }` are [Calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7)
- In the calculated property to can use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and remove e.g. all the numeric digits (`-replace '\d'`) from the `RC` column and assign it to a new `"Row"` (`n="Row"`) column

Comment: ok... So how do i use this... And it doesent convert the first line.
Destination Well Position (Label),Reagents (no vol),Full (Constituent + Tube) ID
TO
Row,Column,*Target Name,*Sample Name

Comment: As i said.. i have a file with this informationon.. I need to edit the file so it looks like correct and save to new filename.

Comment: I can't detail this further as it is unclear what the headers of your  `.\test.csv` file look like. Please, replace the input content in the question under "**I have a CSV file looking like this.**" with the exact first 4 lines of  `.\test.csv` file and format it with the **`{}`** ("*Code sample  <pre><code> Ctrl+K*") icon

Answer (score 0):

Its solved with VBscript instead.